# Trying to use z-index with divs

Tags: html, css, sass, position, z-index

I try desperately to find a solution to my z-index problem. So here I have a div containing 2 other div who respectively have a different background image. I would like to superpose the divs to have the background-image also superimpose. But I can not. Can you help me ?

HTML

```
<div class="right">
    <div class="case"></div>
    <div class="screen"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
div.right {
    position: relative;

    div.screen {
        background-image: url("../../public/screen.svg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    div.case {
        background-image: url("../../public/case.svg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: -2;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are your CSS rules nested? That's not valid CSS

Comment: I using SCSS with compass

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll fix your question with the relevant tags

Comment: Is the issue really z-index or is it that the divs are stacking on top of one another vertically? It maybe be you want to position them differently.

Comment: Yes div appears vertically

Comment: I didn't understand, but if you want superimpose _case_ over _screen_ you just need only to set _absolute_ instead of _relative_ in _position_ on _screen_, then you can set top, left, bottom and right to get the best position inside the _right_ div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 div inside the 'screen' one must have position: absolute. You must that provide values for top and left to place them where you want. I will add a working fiddle.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Meziano/5kcdb9yf/) is a working fiddle.

```
<div class="right">
    <div class="case"></div>
    <div class="screen"></div>
</div>

.right {
  position: relative;
}
.screen {
  background-color: blue;
  left: 10px;
  top:10px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

 div.case {
   background-color: red;
   left: 20px;
   top:20px;
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 3;
  opacity:0.3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? To make one div on top of another you need to change one's position, like top&left or transform:translate

```css
div.right {
    position: relative;
}

div.screen {
    background-color: red; /* i changed the background since i dont have the img */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    top: -75px;
    left: 75px;
}  

div.case {
    background-color: blue;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
 <div class="case"></div>
 <div class="screen"></div>
</div>
```